# css file can't be added in ReactJS both for Bootstrap and Stylesheet

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to insert both my style and bootstrap in my React JS project. But I get the error: Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:8000/bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

I want it to be inserted through the index.html because it's what I am used to. I know the way to insert bootstrap by npm and importing it but I still just want it to be inserted through the index.html.

Hierarchy of files

[image: Hierarchy of files]

Currently the following are my codes:

INDEX.HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Ticketing</title>

        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
        <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./bootstrap-3.3.7-dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="app"></div>
        <script src="/app/bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

WEBPACK.CONFIG.JS

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var path = require("path");

var DIST_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "dist");
var SRC_DIR = path.resolve(__dirname, "src");

var config = {
    entry: SRC_DIR + "/app/index.js",
    output: {
        path: DIST_DIR + "/app",
        filename: "bundle.js",
        publicPath: "/app/"
    },
    module:{
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js?/,
                include: SRC_DIR,
                loader: "babel-loader",
                query:{
                    presets: ["react", "es2015", "stage-2"]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
};

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: there is an npm package for using bootstrap in react. you can go for that also. Here's the link to react bootstrap https://react-bootstrap.github.io/

Comment: thank you for the response, but how about the stylesheet? how do I add it?

Comment: You got the answer or you still need assistance?

Comment: No I got it already. Anton gave me the answer below it works. But Thank You very much for the kind response.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should move the `css` and `style` folder into the src folder. Or try changing `./` to `../`.

Comment: I tried doing that already, but I still can't get it imported to the index.html.

Comment: oh, the moving the bootstrap and style folder works! THANKS!

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much again. :-)

Answer (score 0):

With following steps you can get it:
1st install bootstrap from npm (npm i bootstrap),

go to your app.js file add

@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css'
@import 'YOUR_CSS_FILE.css'